# Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location

I am taking the zip code entered by my user and converting it into a City name. After it is converted to the City name I will save the information into my Firebase Database. I am getting an error "Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'String'" when I try to do this. I am getting the zip code from a text field and passing it from the previous ViewController.
 [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4nGM.png)

```
 //first ViewController


 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{


    if let destination = segue.destination as? SignUpSecondViewController{

    destination.zipCode = zipCodeInput.text! 
    destination.name = nameText.text!
    destination.email = emailText.text!
    destination.password = passwordText.text!
    destination.pictureData = userImageView.image!
    }}

}

   //second ViewController

    var zipCode = String()

 func getLocationFromPostalCode(postalCode : String){
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(postalCode) {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        // Placemarks is an optional array of type CLPlacemarks, first item in array is best guess of Address

        if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {

            if placemark.postalCode == postalCode{
                // you can get all the details of place here
                print("\(placemark.locality)")
                print("\(placemark.country)")
            }
            else{
                print("Please enter valid zipcode")
            }
        }
    }
}




 @IBAction func completeButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

let nameText = name
let emailField = email.lowercased()
let finalEmail = emailField.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
let location = getLocationFromPostalCode(postalCode: zipCode)
let biography = bioTextView.text!
let passwordText = password
let interests = options.joined(separator: " , ")

    var pictureD: NSData?


    if let imageView = self.sentPic.image {
        pictureD = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.sentPic.image!, 0.70) as! NSData
    }


    if  finalEmail.isEmpty || biography.isEmpty || password.isEmpty || pictureD == nil {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "OOPS", message: " You must fill all the fields", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else {
        SVProgressHUD.show()

        self.view.endEditing(true)
        authService.signUP(firstLastName: nameText, email: finalEmail, location: location, biography: biography, password: password, interests: interests, pictureData: pictureD as NSData!)

    }
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()


    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewTabBarViewController") as! UIViewController
    // Alternative way to present the new view controller
     self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Comment: First fix the problem with `let location = getLocationFromPostalCode(postalCode: zipCode)`. That's definitely wrong.

Comment: Is `nameText` is your text field ?

Comment: How can I fix the problem to get the output from that function?

Comment: nameText is a different input, the zipCode text field is for the zip code and I am trying to save it after is is converted to a city name to the location property

Comment: You have to return a string in `getLocationFromPostalCode`.

Comment: var zipLocation = String();
       
zipLocation = getLocationFromPostalCode(postalCode: zipCode) I tried this but get the same error Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem begins with this line:

```
let location = getLocationFromPostalCode(postalCode: zipCode)
```

The problem is that your `getLocationFromPostalCode` has no return value so the compiler thinks that the implicit type of `location` is `()` which means a function with no return (void) type.

So, in theory, you would want to change:

```
func getLocationFromPostalCode(postalCode : String) {
```

to:

```
func getLocationFromPostalCode(postalCode : String) -> String {
```

and have the function return a `String` value.

But, you can't do that either since the implementation of your `getLocationFromPostalCode` consists of getting the location from an asynchronous network call.

The proper solution is to rewrite that function to take a completion handler that returns the obtained location.

```
func getLocationFromPostalCode(postalCode: String, completion: (String?) -> Void) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(postalCode) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        // Placemarks is an optional array of type CLPlacemarks, first item in array is best guess of Address

        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
            if placemark.postalCode == postalCode {
                // you can get all the details of place here
                print("\(placemark.locality)")
                print("\(placemark.country)")
                completion(placemark.locality) // or whatever value you want
                return
            }
            else{
                print("Please enter valid zipcode")
            }
        }

        completion(nil) // no location found
    }
}
```

Now, with that all fixed up, you need to redo how you get the location.

```
@IBAction func completeButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    var pictureD: Data? = nil
    if let imageView = self.sentPic.image {
        pictureD = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView, 0.70)
    }

    let emailField = email.lowercased()
    let finalEmail = emailField.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let biography = bioTextView.text!
    let passwordText = password

    if  finalEmail.isEmpty || biography.isEmpty || password.isEmpty || pictureD == nil {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "OOPS", message: " You must fill all the fields", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else {
        getLocationFromPostalCode(postalCode: zipCode) { (location) in
            guard let location = location else {
                print("no location")
                return
            }

            let nameText = name
            let interests = options.joined(separator: " , ")

            SVProgressHUD.show()

            self.view.endEditing(true)
            authService.signUP(firstLastName: nameText, email: finalEmail, location: location, biography: biography, password: password, interests: interests, pictureData: pictureD!)
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
    }

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewTabBarViewController") as! UIViewController
    // Alternative way to present the new view controller
    self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```